# Figure \ref{fig:figname} does not work as expected

Tags: floats, center

I'm using `\center` command to display a figure over two columns. The problem is that I cannot refer the figure properly. Below is the minimum example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{caption}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{multicol}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    % Dummy texts 
    \kant[1]
\end{multicols}
% Figure
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Picture1.png}
    \label{fig:pic1}
    \captionof{figure}{Sample image 1}
\end{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    % Refer the figure
    As shown in Figure \ref{fig:pic1}, 
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

and this is what I got:
[image]

As highlighted in the screenshot, the figure number is not displayed correctly. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: \label should go after or inside \caption.

Comment: Uh oh, that's right. Thank you for pointing it out! @JohnKormylo